# How do I get my shield to shut up?

Tags: borderlands-2

From a side-quest I have gained a shield that talks.  Pretty amusing at first, but now his chatter is very annoying.  Is there a way to make it stop without affecting any other game audio, and without getting rid of it?

Comment: Get a different shield? Seriously though: that shield is supposed to be annoying (after all, it's AI core did just try to kill you)

Comment: I dunno. It's only tried to kill me a couple of times so far. I think I'll give it another chance.

Comment: That's funny, when I eventually had to give up the AI Core shield and get a new shield I found myself wanting to transplant the personality from the old one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's like the [annoying gun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HC0YSD2H1Q&list=PLDD8FF525D6BC29CB&index=3&feature=plcp), it's a special item that was made this way. Until you find something better I think you can't do anything with it.